# if condition does not work in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function confirmappt(target) {
    var type = document.getElementById("ultrasoundid").value
    var ultrasound = document.getElementById("hdultrasoundid").value
    var appt = document.getElementById('apptdocfacid').value
    appt = 'apptid' + appt + '_1'
    var checkedValue = 'test'
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByName(appt)[i].checked) {
            checkedValue = 'ok'
            break;
        }
    }
    if (checkedValue == 'ok') {
        alert('Please select ultrasound type!');
    }
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to make this appointment?')) 
      return true;
    return false;
}
```

if checkedValue is equal ok both alert and second if condition work. but checkedValue is not equal ok then second if condition does not work. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You could probably understand your code better if it was properly indented.

Comment: I don't follow. There's no `else` word in your code...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `else` block

I think you need

```
if (checkedValue == 'ok') {
    alert('Please select ultrasound type!');
}else{  
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to make this appointment?');
}
```

Comment: checkbox is checked that time it works properly but checkbox is not not checked, confirm message is not showing,,,

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your problem statement that you want alert if checkValue is "ok" and  confirm dialog when if checkValue is not "ok"only

use

```
if (checkedValue == 'ok') {
        alert('Please select ultrasound type!');

    }else{
       if (confirm('Are you sure you want to make this appointment?')) 
      return true;
```

}

Comment: I used it but still same problem. else condition does not work.